# Is it possible to copy a 1D array to a 2D array as described and if so, how?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, xna, copy

The example below is in C# pulling data from Texture2D in XNA. My understanding is that Texture2D.GetData can not be used to pull data into a 2D array initially.

If a 1D array contains values like so: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`

Is it possible to copy that single dimensional array into a 2D array where the 2D array then has the values like so:

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
```

My goal is to copy the whole array from 1D to 2D rather than iterating through and calculating indexes. My current code is like this:

```
    Color[,] TextureDataTo2DArray(Texture2D texture)
    {
        Color[] colors1D = new Color[texture.Width * texture.Height];
        texture.GetData(colors1D);

        Color[,] colors2D = new Color[texture.Width, texture.Height];
        for (int x = 0; x < texture.Width; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < texture.Height; y++)
                colors2D[x, y] = colors1D[x + y * texture.Width];

        return colors2D;
    }
```

Comment: This can easily be done with unsafe code and memcpy, thanks to the fact that in a multidimensional array, elements are stored in memory just as in a single dimensional array.

Comment: What is the problem now? You get an error or is the output unexpected (what is the output ?)

Comment: @YoryeNathan Is there a "safe code" option using memcpy in C#?

Comment: @TimWinter At first, I thought about `Array.Copy`, but I'm not sure it has a 2D to 1D option. And yes, you can use memcpy with IntPtr.

Comment: It looks like you're copying from a 2D array into a 1D array and back into a 2D array the same size as the original 2D array--why get the 1D array involved?

Comment: btw, you dont need to do `x + y * width`, do height iteration the outer one, and just use colors1D[i++]

Comment: @MichelKeijzers I have never done a copy of a 1D array to a 2D array. There are no errors, it is completely functional (from what I have done thus far). I am looking for a way to do it in one go rather than iterating as I said in the question "My goal is to copy the whole array from 1D to 2D rather than iterating through and calculating indices."

Comment: @AlanGilbert This is C# using Texture2D from XNA. texture.GetData can not be used with a 2D array, so getting those values HAS to come in to a 1D array as far as I know.

Comment: Have you tried passing a 2D array into texture.GetData()?

Answer (score 1):

In copying a 1D array into a 2D array, modular arithmetic is your friend:

```
Color[,] TextureDataTo2DArray(Texture2D texture)
    {
        Color[] colors1D = new Color[texture.Width * texture.Height];
        texture.GetData(colors1D);

        Color[,] colors2D = new Color[texture.Width, texture.Height];
        for (int i = 0; i < colors1D.Length; i++)
            colors2D[Math.Floor(i / texture.Width), i % texture.Width] = colors1D[i];

        return colors2D;
    }
```

Ultimately, though, if you're reshaping an array, you're going to have to calculate the correspondence between one shape and another.

Comment: Hey, it works. Probably not as efficient or as clean as some would do it (let's face it, this is a rather C-like approach) but it works.

Comment: Thanks for the "compliment," @ShotgunNinja

Answer (score 0):

You could just increment a counter

```
index = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < texture.Width; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < texture.Height; y++)
        colors2D[x, y] = colors1D[index++];
```

Comment: `index++` is so much nicer, and you can even do it in the indexing: `colors2D[x, y] = colors1D[index++]`

Answer (score 0):

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int Size_of_OneDimensional = 0;
            int Start_Index = 0;
            int row = 0;
            int column=0;


            Console.WriteLine("Enter The number of elements you want to add in 1-D Array : ");
            Size_of_OneDimensional = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int[] One_Dimensional = new int[Size_of_OneDimensional];

                for (int i = 0; i < Size_of_OneDimensional; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter "+i+" Element");
                        One_Dimensional[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    }

                Console.WriteLine("Emter Number of Row : ");
                row = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Emter Number of Colum : ");
                column= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                int[,] Two_Dimensional = new int[row, column];

                Console.WriteLine("Here is your 2-D Array");

                for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
                    {
                    if (Start_Index == One_Dimensional.Length)
                        break;
                    for(int j = 0; j < column; j++)
                        {
                        Two_Dimensional[i, j] = One_Dimensional[Start_Index];
                        Start_Index++;     
                        Console.Write(Two_Dimensional[i, j]);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Can you add some text explaining the problem and how you've solved it?