# Set an array member inside a 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a 2d array `group`

```cs
float[,] group = new float [2,3];
```

My understanding is that, after this line of code I have 2 3-elements arrays in `group`.

`{{3elements},{3elements}}`

I also have `member`

```cs
float[] member = new float[3] {1,2,3};
```

I want to set the first array inside the 2d array "group" to match "member" so that I can have `{{1,2,3},{}}`

I tried `group[0] = member;`

But I got an error. What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: _"I have 2 3-elements arrays in group"_ -- your understanding is incorrect. You have a **two-dimensional** array. It's a single array, with rows and columns. If you want for an array of array, you need a **jagged array**, e.g. `float[][] group = { new float[3], new float[3] };`. Of course, if you're just going to initialize the members explictly, then you can just do `float[][] group = new float[][2]; group[0] = member;` It's not clear what it is you _actually_ want here.

Comment: @SvenRasmussen: no, that's incorrect. If they specify both indexes for the 2d array, then they can only assign a single `float` value, not a `float[]` like they want.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339883/is-it-possible-to-copy-a-1d-array-to-a-2d-array-as-described-and-if-so-how, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567329/multidimensional-array-vs, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays

Comment: Thanks guys. I thought doing float[2,3] group and float[][] group = { new float[3], new float[3] } is just that the second method allows arrays of different lengths to be inside the parent array. What are the differences between these two methods beside "doing different child array length" and "set members explicitly"?

Comment: Good read, thanks Peter

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
        float[,] group = new float[2, 3];
        float[] member = new float[3] { 1, 2, 3 };

        for(int i = 0; i < member.Length; i++)
        {
            group[0, i] = member[i];
        }
```